# Actualizar relación con otra trabla, mediante eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Mi versión de Laravel 5.2, he desarrollado un modelo que esta relacionado con otro,(many).
Esto es lo que tengo en el create.

```
 public function createBlog(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    
    $author = '';
   
    $blog= new Blog;
    $authors = $data['author'];
    $data['author'] = '';
    $blog->fill($data);
    $blog->notification_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $blog->save();



    $author_content = array();
    $autores = array();
    $content_found = Blog::find($blog->id);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($authors); $i++) {
        # code...
        $auxAuthor = array(
            'id_user' => $authors[$i],
            'id_content' => $blog->id,
        );

        $author = new AuthorContent;
        $author->id_user = $authors[$i];
        $author->id_content = $blog->id;

        //$author->save();

        array_push($author_content, $author);
    }

    $content_found->ContentAuthors()->saveMany($author_content);
    $content_found = null;
 

    return response()
        ->json(['data' => $content_heritage, 'request' => $data, 'author_content' => $author_content]);
}
```

mi modelo

```
public function ContentAuthors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AuthorContent::class,'id_user', 'id_content');
    }
```

Pero mi duda es como hago para actualizar, ya sea por que los autores pueden cambiar y el número  aumentar y disminuir.
Como tendría que hacer esto para que tuviera encuenta estos cambios.

Si por ejemplo guardo dos autores, regreso a la entrada del blog, y cambio y ahora solo hay un autor.

La idea es como tengo que realizar la parte del update, para que actualice la tabla de autores.

He intentado en la parte de update pero, con sync pero tampoco lo consigo

```
$contents = Manifestationcontens::find($data['id']);
            $content_found = Manifestationcontens::find($data['id']);
     
            $authors = $data['author'];
            $data['author'] = '';

            $author_content = array();
           
            $count_authors = count($authors);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($authors); $i++) {

                $author = new AuthorContent;
                $author->id_user = $authors[$i];
                $author->id_content = $data['id'];
                //$author->save();

                //$author->save();
                
                array_push($author_content, $author);
            }
            $content_found->ContentAuthors()->sync($author_content);
```

pero no consigo actualizar los valores me sale Illegal offset type

Comment: No termino de entender la duda expuesta, por favor lee [ask], edita y trata de guiar mejor la publicación

Comment: Cuando tengo que acutalizar el blog, si los autores añadidos han cambiado, se han añadido o eliminado. Que tendría que realizar para actualizar dicha relación teniendo estos casos contemplados.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta agrega ahi esos detalles y si puedes colocar un ejemplo de lo que deseas realizar sería de mucha ayuda para clarificar

Comment: Ya entendí mejor la duda, ¿cómo definiste la llave foránea en tu migración?

Comment: No hay llave foranea, ya que fue una tabla que se añadio a última hora, pero si tienes un ejmplo me serviría.

Comment: Pues ahí existe un problema de diseño, por ejemplo si carece de esa fk enconvrs como identificas a cada autor en cada entrada?

Comment: Hola BetaM. Aún no lo tengo claro, también que yo estoy continuando un proyecto ya existente, y aunque el blog y author los he creado yo, author apunta a users y blog, los cuales guardo en id_user, ir_content, la pregunta donde debe ir la llave foranea enblog o en author?.Gracias por tu tiempo.